# Extra "ghostly" camera button when using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

On a communityapp development, I have the task of making an iPhone app into an iPad app.

Following the documentation, I used the following code to spawn my camera view :

```
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
        if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
            if ([UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront]) {
                self.imagePickerController.cameraDevice =  UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
            }
            self.imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
            self.imagePickerController.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto;
        }

        popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.imagePickerController];
        [popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.profilePicture.frame
                                 inView:self.view
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                               animated:YES];
        return;
    }
```

But when spawned, I get this annoying "extra ghostly" camera button...

[image: This button is NOT welcome...]

It doesn't work, and seems only to taunt me.

If I ask the object to hide its input buttons, ALL buttons disappear. I see no way of being able to tell that specific button to sod off.

### UPDATE

I discovered it's only there the first time. If I close and reopen the popover, it's gone...

Comment: +1 for the best image I've seen on a Stack Overflow question by far. :)

Comment: Thanks @Fogmeister, trying to capture my frustration over that ghostly UI element of torment...

Comment: Have you tried to dispatch it on the next run loop, just a dispatch_async  that calls the popover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this appears to be a bug in iOS 6 itself. There are a few possible workarounds, however.

You can set the `showsCameraControls` property of the image picker to false. This will remove the ghostly image, but, the other controls will be removed as well. You'll have to write your own view with buttons and whatnot to call the correct actions.

You say if you close and reopen the popover, the button goes away. It may be possible for you to set the `showsCameraControls` property of the picker to false, and then back to true before the picker is displayed. If it doesn't work, try creating a sort-of fake open/close action when the picker is initialized.

Comment: I had to "secretly" open it, close it, then open it again to solve this. But you are correct :]